# What's the meaning of "würde"?

Tags: etymology, meaning

I know the meaning of the following sentence

> Ich würde gerne einen Termin machen.

Trying to better understand the words like *wollen*, *gern*, *möchten*, *würde* etc., I realized that the meaning of *würde* seems to be very strange.

According to two dictionaries its meaning sounds like *dignity*, *elevation*, *majesty*, *to become*?.

At the end I could find a dictionary with the right definition: *would / will*.

But why the same word [can be translated in so different way](http://it.bab.la/dizionario/tedesco-inglese/wuerde)?

Can you help me to understand the etymology of so different meanings?

(Further translations by [WordReference.com](http://www.wordreference.com/deen/w%C3%BCrde) and [bab.la](http://it.bab.la/dizionario/tedesco-italiano/wuerde#st).)

Comment: What I could find with a quick look in two dictionaries is that the origin of "Würde" is not completely clear, but it is probably derived from "Wert". That would mean that the homophony with "würde" (from "werden") is merely accidental. Anyway, as a German learner you should treat it as such.

Comment: In any language, words exist that are spelled equally but may have nothing in common. Ex. "Ball" in German **and** English is either a round object for playing, or a formal party. Another example in German: Gerade/gerade. In your case, you're comparing the noun "Würde" (dignity) with a conjugation of "werden" (to become) which happen to be spelled equally (except for the capitalization).

Comment: In English there is a similar word: I will make an appointment. Will has only slightly to do something with your will or the last will or willpower. würde just means would.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are actually two different words:

**Würde (noun)** does indeed have the meanings you found in the dictionaries (dignity, etc.)
The [duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Wuerde) traces this back to the word **wirdī** in Althochdeutsch.

What you encountered in your example is a form of the verb **werden**, the **Konjunktiv 2**.
This one seems to originate from **werdan** ([duden article on werden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/werden_entwickeln_naehern))

I agree with Carstens comment that these words are not directly related.

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at a slightly simplified version of the sentence:

> Ich würde einen Termin machen.
>
> I would make an appointment.

This, as Hulk said, is *Konjunktiv 2*, which generally expresses *irrealis*, i.e. something hypothetical.

---

Now let's look at "gerne":

> Ich mache etwas gerne.
>
> I like to do something.

"Gerne" is an adverb that means "with pleasure". German usually prefers using this adverb to the construction we see in the English version of this example.

---

If we combine the two we end up with

> Ich würde gerne einen Termin machen.
>
> I would like to make an appointment.

This is -- both in English and German -- a polite way to say "Ich will einen Termin machen" -- "I want to make an appointment". It's what you'd say on the phone when, well, calling someone to make an appointment.

Comment: Could "ich möchte gerne einen Termin machen" also then be used equally or would a native speaker preferably use "würde"?

Comment: That works nicely, too.

Answer (score 1):

*Würde* is indeed the Konjunktiv 2 form of *werden* "become", but the sentence you quote illustrates its use as a marker of subjunctive mood. Here its meaning is no longer about "becoming", but instead expresses that something is not real, or not assumed to be real.

Comment: Aside from the fact that the question was asked more than six years ago, I don't see what your answer contributes that the other answers have not yet mentioned.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: as far as I have learned the age of a question is no reason for anything regarding quality or answers. So I would "keep" only the raised eyebrow for the content.